# How to represent a dataset as a linked list-like graph?

Tags: dataset, visualization, graphs

I would like to visualize [this data set](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/sx-stackoverflow.html) using Python and probably a visualization tool like Matplotlib. The data set contains three columns: a user id with a question, a user id with an answer, and time. I would like to visualize this data set as a linked list style graph. That is a tree-like structure which would show relationships based on the connections between questions and answers. I've tried different sets of keywords in an attempt to find out how to visualize a data set in this way, but to no avail. [I'm new to data science or analysis]. So I would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph resulting from this kind of dataset is also known as a [Network Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory) and the kind of analysis you are trying to do is known as [Social Network Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network_analysis).

There are many prominent Python libraries for visualization and subsequent analysis of network graphs. The most widely used is [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/). It is easy to add nodes and directed edges in a NetworkX graph and visualize them with [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Installing NetworkX is a prerequisite.

`pip install networkx`

The following code creates a NetworkX DiGraph object, adds edges(and thereby nodes) to it and plots the graph.

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (4, 1)])
nx.draw(G)
```

Hopefully, this should get you started :)